# How can we use the actual type pointed to by an empty interface to create a new instance of that type in Go?

Tags: reflection, go, interface

Please check the below program. Var `z` is of type `interface{}`. It stores the type of struct `X`. But I cannot use it to create a new instance of `X`. I have some requirement where I need to keep the type of the object in an `interface{}` variable, and use that to create an instance of that type. Here is a [link for the snippet on go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/RnUwShrz54)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type X struct {
    a int
    b int
}

type MyInt int

func main() {
    x := X{}
    y := reflect.TypeOf(x)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", reflect.New(y))

    var z interface{}
    z = y
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", z) // prints main.X

    //Below line throws the error
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", reflect.New(z)) //----> This line throws error

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to extract the `reflect.Type` value from an `interface{}` value:

```
fmt.Printf("%v\n", reflect.New(z.(reflect.Type))) //----> Works!
```

Your modified example on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/K2c8_fkOhD).

Note that the above example panics if `z` does not hold a value of type `reflect.Type` or if it is `nil`. You can use the special comma-ok form to prevent that:

```
if t, ok := z.(reflect.Type); ok {
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", reflect.New(t))    // t is of type reflect.Type
} else {
    fmt.Println("Not the expected type or nil!")
}
```